# Durandal gives "Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null" error

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Been playing with Durandal 2.1.0, but cannot seem to get an example up an running. When I run it in Chrome I get the error "Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null".

Folder structure is:
-viewmodels

|-vm1.js

-Scripts

|-durandal...

-views

|-vm1.html

-Index.html

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="Scripts\main"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    'text': 'Scripts/text',
    'durandal': 'Scripts/durandal',
    'plugins': 'Scripts/durandal/plugins',
    'viewLocator': 'durandal/viewLocator',
}
});

define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);

define(function (require) {
    var system = require('durandal/system'),
        app = require('durandal/app'),
        router = require('plugins/router');

    system.debug(true);

    app.start().then(function () {
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/vm1');
});
});
```

**vm1.js:**

```
define(['plugins/router'], function (router) {
    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            //This line never fires
            alert();
        }
    }
});
```

PS: Installed with nuget. Assume any JS errors are typos, the script itself is ok. I have tried all manner of things moving the order of script loads around, using viewLocator to define the path manually. Seems to correspond perfectly to the examples I've seen on Durandal's site.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I went back to it and found the problem. I had not added <div id="applicationHost"></div> to my HTML. Doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're specifying paths directly, or using a custom viewLocator, you need to place your *views* directory and your *viewmodels* directory on the same level.  In other words, they need to be siblings in the tree.

Take a look at our main entry point in **main.js**.  I have removed the irrelevant bits:

```
function (system, app, viewLocator, bindings, extenders, validations) {
    //>>excludeStart("build", true);
    system.debug(true);
    //>>excludeEnd("build");        

    //Initialize KnockoutJS customizations
    bindings.init();
    extenders.init();        

    app.title = 'Some Application';

    app.configurePlugins({
        router: true,
        dialog: true,
        widget: true
    });

    app.start().then(function() {
        //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
        //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application with a transition.
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
    });
});
```

I don't see where you call `viewLocator.useConvention()`, or otherwise customize the `viewLocator`.

Also, where's your *App* directory?  We have the following (among many other directories):

> App
>
> > views
> >
> > viewmodels

*App* is at the top level of our Web project on the server.

Answer (score 2):

So, I've been playing with Durandal/ Knockout for some time and I had a similar issue in the beginning. All the other answers are useful and more relevant if you've started using Knockout in your app. But since I was getting this error even before using Knockout, I did a line-by-line breakdown of my code.

Turns out, I had not added the div#applicationHost element in my index.html file. That's it. Simply adding this solved my issue.

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="applicationHost">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, it's not absolutely necessary to always have a div with this ID, but then you will have to manually compose your application. You can read some more on [this discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/M1A9dRp-ILo).

Comment: Thanks! I was in the process of porting an old project template over and missed this!